# How can I beam the URL change on one page to another page?

Tags: javascript

I am writing some code currently being tested on localhost. The URL of one page that I am working on changes occasionally to add something after the `#` sign. For example,

It will change from:

```
http://localhost/something.php#/4
```

to

```
http://localhost/something.php#/5
```

I want the other page open in the second monitor of the same PC with URL `http://localhost/anything.php` to know about it.

My first thought to do this was with a `setInterval` that would regularly check the `localStorage` for the current URL of the `something.php` page.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this so that I don't have to make frequent checks with `setInterval`?

Can the `something.php` page beam its status of being changed to the other page whenever the URL change happens?

Thanks.

Comment: So you basically wish to change the URL opened in the another tab whenever there is a change in the first tab of the browser?

Comment: @nice_dev For now, I just want to update some content on the second page when the URL of the first page changes. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Listen for the [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) event and send a message over a [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel).

```js
const bc = new BroadcastChannel("location");
window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
    bc.postMessage(location.hash)
})

bc.addEventListener('message', function(e){
    location.hash = e.data;
})

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => bc.close())
```

Comment: Thanks @Spectric. :) I have two questions. Does this whole code go into `something.php`? If so, how will `anything.php` know about it?

If the top part goes into `something.php` and the bottom part into `anything.php`, won't I get errors about the variable `bc`?

Comment: @RealNoob yes, the whole code goes into both files. Both pages will know about messages because the channel is shared across tabs/windows.

Comment: Thanks @Spectric. Just one more question. It is fine if I just put the broadcasting code on the `something.php` page and the receiving code on the `anything.php` page right? It worked for me as long as I created the variable `bc` on both pages but I wasn't entirely sure.

Comment: @RealNoob if you only want changes in `something.php`'s URL to be broadcast, then just remove the `hashchange` listener on the other pages.